# How do i convert my okhttp response to Class or List<ClassName>?

Tags: java, android, gson, okhttp

I am new to android and learning android. 
I am using Okhttp library for httpcalls in program. i have made rest api for Simple Get Request.

> api/FeaturedCourses (URL)

This My Response

```
[
  {
    "$id": "1",
    "ExamId": 44,
    "ImageName": "637064732146027131.jpg",
    "ExamName": "Some Exam Name",
    "Description": "Some Long Description Goes Here.",
    "SellPriceUSD": 10,
    "SellPriceINR": 490
  }
]
```

In okhttp i am have done till here.

```
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {    
                String data = response.body().string();
                nsjdemo.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        txtString.setText(data);
                    }
                });
            }
```

This is displaying API Response in TextBox. But i want to Bind Api Response to List. So later i can bind it to recyclerview or listview.

Comment: The main difference between Json and Array is Json is shown in **{** and Array shown in **[**

Comment: Either use a JSON parser directly or use Retrofit instead of OkHttp (where it will help you parse the JSON).

Comment: @Ashish thank you for the information. Can you please give me solution to achieve this

Comment: So you want to parse your `Json` response to an Array of ResponseObjects am I right?

Comment: @Ashish I have tried with JSON Response too but not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After Searching a lot i found answer, without changing Server Code.

```
String jsonOutput = response;
Type listType = new TypeToken<List<DemoClass>>(){}.getType();
List<DemoClass> posts = gson.fromJson(jsonOutput, listType);
```